# Reproducing loadings from autoplot in ggfortify for PCA

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggfortify

I'm using `autoplot` in `ggfortify` to plot a `prcomp` object. I also wanted to see if I could manually reproduce the plot. However, when I do this, the two plots seems to differ in terms of how the loadings are plotted. Note that the dataset is not scaled here. The dataset that I'm actually doing this exercise on has the same units for all columns, and I figure not scaling may be consequential.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
data(mtcars)
cars_pca = prcomp(mtcars, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE)
autoplot(cars_pca, loadings = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)

plot(x = cars_pca$x[, 1], y = cars_pca$x[, 2])
text(x = cars_pca$rotation[, 1], 
     y = cars_pca$rotation[, 2],
     col = alpha('red', 0.7),
     cex = 1,
     labels = colnames(mtcars))
```

I've read that `R` uses the terms loading and eigenvector interchangeably even when that's not precise. However, I'm unable to produce the `ggfortify` biplot even when implementing manually what's detailed in these [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104306/what-is-the-difference-between-loadings-and-correlation-loadings-in-pca-and) [questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another). I also tried looking for the source code for `ggfortify::autoplot.prcomp` but no luck.

Can someone give me some advice for how to reproduce the loadings that `ggfortify` is plotting? I'd really like to understand what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation is happening in the `ggfortify::autoplot.prcomp` function. Since you are using the default value of `scale=1` then the values are adjusted. Here's how to recover the same points plotted during the `autoplot`. The loadings are transformed in the `ggfortify::ggbiplot` function

```
scaler <- cars_pca$sdev[c(1,2)] * sqrt(nrow(cars_pca$x))
trans <- t(t(cars_pca$x[, 1:2]) / scaler)
scaler2 <- min(max(abs(trans[, 1L])) / max(abs(cars_pca$rotation[, 1L])),
              max(abs(trans[, 2L])) / max(abs(cars_pca$rotation[, 2L])))
trans2 <- cars_pca$rotation[, 1L:2L] * scaler2 * 0.8

plot(x = trans[, 1], y = trans[, 2])
text(x = trans2[, 1], 
     y = trans2[, 2],
     col = alpha('red', 0.7),
     cex = 1,
     labels = colnames(mtcars))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain where `scaler` and `trans` come from? I was looking for similar formulas but the closest things I could find were these two questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104306/what-is-the-difference-between-loadings-and-correlation-loadings-in-pca-and. I'm having trouble mapping between the objects in your code and the objects in the formulas of those two questions. Thanks!

Comment: Those just came from the `autoplot.prcomp` function: https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/4b620a965e6c09a1db5b83f835bdcd18467a5634/R/fortify_stats.R#L267

Comment: Hm, even after scaling the data points, the loadings do not appear in the same positions manually as they do in autoplot. I'm reading through the source you sent (very helpful!) but I cant seem to figure out why this would be the case.

Comment: I've updated with code for the loadings. Those were transformed as well in the `ggbiplot` function itself: https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/4b620a965e6c09a1db5b83f835bdcd18467a5634/R/plotlib.R#L571

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the scaling factor used for plotting the loading positions in `ggfortify` is not some function of the eigenvalues, but rather the entries of each eigenvector is just scaled up by the plot window (and then multiplied by 0.8 for neatness)?